# lscpu vulnerabilities

Tags: kernel, cpu

I've never seen this before I installed Ubuntu 20.04.

The `lscpu` output now shows some vulnerabilities on some CPU's.

For example:

```
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

What does this really mean? Does the kernel really mitigate the vulnerabilities? Where can I find more information about it?

It looks like with this `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz` CPU this is the first kernel that works well without random freezes.

Comment: Also found `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*`. Some of those exploits [run on JavasScript](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-this-spectre-proof-of-concept-shows-how-dangerous-these-attacks-can-be/). 
The only vulnerable bit seems [symmetric multi threading](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html#malicious-guest-in-a-virtual-machine) (SMT; HyperThreading on Intel)
More info on [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this really mean?

Several security issues have been discovered in the last few years in several processors. Copied from the [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown):

> In January 2018, security researchers announced a new class of side
>   channel attacks that impact most processors, including processors from
>   Intel, AMD, ARM and IBM. The attack allows malicious userspace
>   processes to read kernel memory and malicious code in guests to read
>   hypervisor memory.

.

> Does the kernel really mitigate the vulnerabilities?

Yes, and it includes the compiler also, as some changes were needed there.
And it has been expensive in terms throughput in specific areas. My best example is "pipe-test" where two tasks ping-pong each other at high rate. My use case is testing idle governors for the very shallow idle states used by such a high work/idle frequency. Anyway, the typical loop time on my i7-2600K test system has steady increased from ~ 3 microseconds per loop a couple of years ago to about 6.5 with kernel 5.7. In other types of workflows the degradation due to these mitigations has been undetectable.

Some of these mitigations can be turned off in the kernel configuration, but I have never tried it.

> Where can I find more information about it?

I do not know the best reference, but try [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown).

These are the listings for:
i5-9600K

```
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Mitigation; TSX disabled
```

i7-2600K:

```
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

Answer (score 0):

A few more things more, extending the excellent Doug Smythies answer:

Also found `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*`. Some of those exploits [run on JavasScript](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-this-spectre-proof-of-concept-shows-how-dangerous-these-attacks-can-be/).

The only exploit left vulnerable seems [symmetric multi threading](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html#malicious-guest-in-a-virtual-machine) (SMT; HyperThreading on Intel), but maybe [could be ignored on most cases](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacytoolsIO/comments/ehqqeb/what_does_smt_vulnerable_mean/).

More info on [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html).